# Is there a way to go to the start of the void loop() function kind of like a "continue" keyword in c in loops?

Tags: programming

I am new to Arduino programming and am trying to make an obstacle avoiding car with an ultrasonic sensor and a differential driver model. While learning how to code it, I learned that you can exit the `void loop()` function with an `exit(0)` to terminate the program analogous to `break` keyword in C language.
Is there anything similar that I can use to mimic the "continue" keyword, say if I don't want to run the code after a particular line in the `void loop()` function.

Comment: If you `return` from the `loop()` function, you immediately end the execution of the current iteration. The `loop()` function will then start again, as its always looping (therefor the naming). `loop()` is just a function like any other. It just gets called over and over in an infinite loop.

Comment: Using "return;" as if it were a normal function seemed to work. I thought at first that return would do the same thing as exit(0). Thank you so much @chrisl.

Comment: I think an`exit(0)` will just lead into an infinite loop,which is doing nothing. On a microcontroller there must run a code at anytime. It cannot give the control back to an OS.

Comment: yes, I have heard using exit(0) is a bad Arduino programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop() function, `return` will perform that function. By exiting the function, the for() loop in main() (which we don't see) will iterate again, calling `loop()` again.

Another way to accomplish the same thing is to write everything in your `setup()` function, including whatever kind of loop construct you want, and use `break;` and `continue;` statements as you're used to:

```
void setup(){
   // pinMode() & digitalWrite() calls
   // Initialize the Serial port if you need to
   // Any other one-time setup
   //
   // Everything happens here:
   for( .... ){
      // loop contents here
      if( whatever ){
         continue;
      }
      else if( something_else ){
         break;
      }
   }
}

// This just stalls forever when setup() ends:
void loop(){
   ;
}
```